# Changing the javascript value of a URL with hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my links in currmenu div to do the following. I need them to change the value of the URL that is in the javascript. Then have the script load the new page into the pdf div.

All the files I link will be internal and on the company intranet. I have to use the preexisting site and add this new feature. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<link href="css/pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pdfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function (){

    var msg;
    var s = document.getElementById("statement");   
    var params = { 

        url: "Docs/6-Week Calendar.pdf",

        pdfOpenParams: {

            navpanes: 0,
            toolbar: 0,
            statusbar: 0,
            view: "FitV"

        }

    };

    var myPDF = new PDFObject(params).embed("pdf");

    if(myPDF){
        msg = "The PDF was successfully embedded!";
        s.className = "success";
    } else {
        msg = "It appears the embed didn't work.";
        s.className = "fail";
    }
            s.innerHTML = msg;
    };
</script>

</head>
<body>
   <div class="currmenulist">
   <li><a href="Docs/New Employee onboarding curriculum.pdf">Link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>

 </div>  
<div id="pdf">It appears you don't have Adobe Reader or PDF support in this web 
browser. <a href="Docs/6-Week Calendar.pdf">Click here to download the PDF</a></div> <p 
id="statement"> </p>  

</body>
```

Comment: why is it tagged jQuery?

Comment: I would assume it's tagged jQuery because he has that available to use. The answer I posted uses jQuery and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work for you

```
window.onload = function () {

   var params = {
         url: "Docs/6-Week Calendar.pdf",
         pdfOpenParams: {
            navpanes: 0,
            toolbar: 0,
            statusbar: 0,
            view: "FitV"
         }
      },
      s = document.getElementById("statement");

   function loadPDF() {
      var msg,
          myPDF = new PDFObject(params).embed("pdf");

      if (myPDF) {
         msg = "The PDF was successfully embedded!";
         s.className = "success";
      } 
      else {
         msg = "It appears the embed didn't work.";
         s.className = "fail";
      }
      s.innerHTML = msg;
   }

   var linklist = document.getElementsByClassName('currmenulist')[0],
       pdfLinks = linklist.getElementsByTagName('a');

   for (var k = 0; k < pdfLinks.length; k++) {

      //here you can add validation, i.e, if href ends with .pdf etc
      if (pdfLinks[k].getAttribute('href') == '' || pdfLinks[k].getAttribute('href') == '#')
         continue;

      pdfLinks[k].addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
         ev.preventDefault();

         params.url = ev.target.getAttribute('href');
         loadPDF();
      });
   }

   loadPDF();
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working like a charm. I hope you have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need:

```
var msg;
var s = document.getElementById("statement");
var params = { 
    url: "Docs/6-Week Calendar.pdf",
    pdfOpenParams: {
        navpanes: 0,
        toolbar: 0,
        statusbar: 0,
        view: "FitV"
    }
};

window.onload = function (){
    var myPDF = new PDFObject(params).embed("pdf");

    if(myPDF){
        msg = "The PDF was successfully embedded!";
        s.className = "success";
    } else {
        msg = "It appears the embed didn't work.";
        s.className = "fail";
    }
    s.innerHTML = msg;
};

$(".currmenulist a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    params.url = $(this).attr("href");

    var myPDF = new PDFObject(params).embed("pdf");

    if(myPDF){
        msg = "The PDF was successfully embedded!";
        s.className = "success";
    } else {
        msg = "It appears the embed didn't work.";
        s.className = "fail";
    }
    s.innerHTML = msg;
});
```

Comment: If you set the href attribute of the links to be the PDFs you need loaded, this will prevent the page from navigating and will load the PDF into the div.

Comment: I feel so stupid for asking this, but how do you set the href attributes to the PDFs?  I tried the following
<a href="Docs/New Employee onboarding curriculum.pdf#pdf">Link 1</a>
Thank you for the fast response.

Comment: `<a href="Docs/6-Week Calendar.pdf">Link 2</a>`

Comment: I just tried that with three of my PDFs and all three opened in a new window. Only the calendar opened on load.